# css rtl after ltr not working on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This piece of code work right on all browser except chrome

the parent div has ltr role, after there is a childrens ul li with direction rtl.

somehow the child direction can't be override and inherit from the parent.

```
<div class="offerVica" id="changeDeal4" style="direction: ltr; height: 78.1052631578947px; max-width: 380px; position: relative;">

                        <ul class="bjqs" style="height: 78.1052631578947px; display: block;">
                            <li class="bjqs-slide" style="height: 78.1052631578947px; width: 371px; direction: rtl !important;">
                                <a href="#" style="direction:rtl">
                                    <div class="vicDate" style="direction: rtl!important;"><span>17</span>-<span>21</span>.<span>8</span>.<span>2014 </span>(<span>first</span>-<span>last</span>)</div>
                                    <div class="price" style="direction:rtl;">example<span>2200 </span></div>
                                    <div class="lastPrice" style="direction:rtl;">1,920 </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

this is the code on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wy2f2a74/1/

as you can see most browser render it fine except chrome.

any idea how to fix on chrome?

Comment: The only difference I'm seeing between chrome and FF is the text alignment.

Comment: it's not text alignment but a direction problem

Comment: Perhaps you can explain further then?  Adding text-align makes them nearly identical in FF and chrome:  https://jsfiddle.net/wy2f2a74/3/

Answer (score 1):

The user agent stylesheet adds `text-align` property to elements like `li`, `a`, `span`, which contain text.

When adding `direction: ltr` to a parent element, the value for this text-align is inherited as `left`.

So now the direction for `li` is `rtl`, but it inherits `text-align:left` from parent. So we need to set it manually to `right`.

If you check the `ul` tag, the user agent stylesheet does not add the `text-align` property to the `ul`. So applying `direction:rtl` to `ul` will work instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get "rtl" to work until I learned from https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/:

> There is also a specific HTML tag that can be used for changing the
>   direction of text: `<bdo>`, the bidirectional override element. This
>   exists so there is a semantics-free element to use just for this purpose.

This is what I used, which worked for me:

`<bdo dir="rtl">moc.liame@elpmas</bdo>`