# Why "direction: rtl" in CSS does not work on Chromium based browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a simple test html code:

```css
.heb {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is test with some Hebrew text <span class="heb">◌ָ</span> using CSS. As you can see, the font-family and the font-size work. But the text direction does not work on Chrome. But it works on Safari.
</p>

<p>
  This is test with some Hebrew text <span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 24px;" dir="rtl">◌ָ</span>. The text direction attribute here works on both Safari and Chrome.
</p>
```

Safari and Firefox can render both correctly:
[image]

But Google Chrome, Brave, Vivaldi, etc cannot:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css rtl after ltr not working on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034855/css-rtl-after-ltr-not-working-on-chrome)

Comment: I came across this post before. But I did not quite understand fully. I tried to this span.heb {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";  
}
It does not work either.

Comment: Also, it does not seem to address why it works well on Safari and Firefox but does not work on Chromium based browsers.

Comment: BTW, you can click "Run code snippet" in my post on `Chromium based browsers` and on `Safari/Firefox` for comparison.

Comment: in that post they say you should add `text-align:right` . also, the problem might be regarding the symbol you use. Check Chromium forums. You might find something there. or post a bug report there

Comment: The HTML dir attribute does not simply apply the CSS `direction` property. It applies that and also a `unicode-bidi` property which varies with the element it's assigned to. The CSS level 3 spec for direction says "Authors should not use direction in HTML documents." and likewise for unicode-bidi. It advises using the dir attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Alohci. It’s interesting though why all other browsers (I tested) are able to recognize the dir attribute in css except for the chromium based browsers.

Comment: Hi @MihaiT, thanks. But text-align is different thing from dir.